# how to fix this? java homework

Tags: java

i have homework

this is my question

[image]

and my code is

```
public class DisplayTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        int seconds = 290;
        int hour = seconds/60/60;
        int minute = seconds/60;

        seconds = seconds%60;      

        System.out.printf("The amount of [ 290 ] seconds are %02d:%02d:%02d\n",hour,minute,seconds);

         seconds = 7650;
         hour = seconds/60/60;
         minute  = seconds/60;

         seconds = seconds%60;

         System.out.printf("The amount of [ 7650 ] seconds are %02d:%02d:%02d\n",hour,minute,seconds);
    }
}
```

my output in 7650 is not same why ? :(

and my solution is it true?

Comment: By the way, your question asks you to create a program that is able to convert seconds into hour,minute and seconds. Here you are just trying to do it for two values (290 and 7650). Make it generic to be qualified as an answer else you will fail in this homework

Comment: If you are too lazy to add a question, you can add a screenshot containing only the interesting part ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you didn't minus the hours for minutes, so the hours are double counted. That is, use `minute = seconds / 60 - hour * 60;` instead of `minute = seconds / 60;` you will get the correct results.

Actually for the first part (`The amount of [ 290 ] seconds are 00:04:50`) you should also modify the code. The reason it looks good is because 290 seconds is less than an hour, so the problem did not appear.

Here is full code:

```
public class DisplayTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int seconds = 290;
        int hour = seconds / 60 / 60;
        int minute = seconds / 60 - hour * 60;;

        seconds = seconds % 60;

        System.out.printf("The amount of [ 290 ] seconds are %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, seconds);

        seconds = 7650;
        hour = seconds / 60 / 60;
        minute = seconds / 60 - hour * 60;

        seconds = seconds % 60;

        System.out.printf("The amount of [ 7650 ] seconds are %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, seconds);
    }
}
```

Here are the results:

```
The amount of [ 290 ] seconds are 00:04:50
The amount of [ 7650 ] seconds are 02:07:30
```

Comment: @Mohannad Thanks a lot and happy weekend :-)

Answer (score 6):

As @Balwinder mentioned in his comment, you might do well to have a helper method which accepts seconds and prints out the formatted display time.  The code below accomplishes this in just a few lines.

```
public static void printHMS(int secs) {
    int seconds = secs % 60;
    int minutes = (secs / 60) % 60;
    int hours   = (secs / 60) / 60;

    System.out.printf("The amount of [ %d ] seconds are %02d:%02d:%02d\n", secs, hours, minutes, seconds);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    printHMS(290);
    printHMS(7650);
}
```

**Output:**

```
The amount of [ 290 ] seconds are 00:04:50
The amount of [ 7650 ] seconds are 02:07:30
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do** it like a pro:

```
    /*** Returns the Time**/
public static String getTimeEdited(int seconds) {

    if (seconds / 60 > 60) // Is more than one hour>60
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",(seconds/60)/60,(seconds/60)%60,seconds%60);
    else                  // Is less than one hour<60
        return String.format("%02d:%02d",(seconds/60)%60,seconds%60);


}
```